How to get the user's street address?
This is how I get the user's consent:
const { code } = getAuthParams(
  await chrome.identity.launchWebAuthFlow({
    interactive: true,
    url: `https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth?${new URLSearchParams({
      redirect_uri: REDIRECT_URI,
      client_id: CLIENT_ID,
      access_type: "offline",
      response_type: "code",
      prompt: "consent",
      scope: [
        "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile",
        "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email",
        "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/user.birthday.read",
        "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/user.gender.read",
        "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/user.addresses.read"
      ].join(" ")
    })}`
  })
);
const authData = await getGoogleAuthData({ code });

So far, I attempted to get the street address with the following:
const json = await (await fetch("https://people.googleapis.com/v1/people/me?personFields=birthdays,genders,addresses", {
  headers: {
    Authorization: `Bearer ${authData.access_token}`
  }
})).json();

However, the JSON response only contains birthdays and genders

Since you're already using the https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile scope, can you confirm if your users have their addresses set in the About me section of their Google Accounts that's set to Visible to anyone?

I see addresses under https://myaccount.google.com/personal-info , not https://myaccount.google.com/profile

From what I know, the addresses set under Personal info are different from the ones set in the About me section of Google accounts. The prior is private and not visible to others, while the latter can be set to be visible publicly, which is what the People API, v1 gets. Try adding one there by selecting Add contact info > Add address and see if it works.

I also found this Stack Overflow post to have a similar issue as yours. However, it uses PHP instead of JavaScript.

@Saddles Right, I have tried it indeed and it worked, but I cannot expect the user to manually enter an address beforehand; I assume that the average user only puts a home address in his Google Maps
